# Do in MySQL i really must create temporary table before insert there

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I wanna use temporary table to avoid field names enumeration inside SELECT clause. And try to do it so:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable 
FROM Acts;

ALTER TABLE #TempTable 
DROP COLUMN id, 
DROP COLUMN numOfAct;

UPDATE #TempTable 
SET dateOfAct = NOW();

SELECT * FROM #TempTable;
DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

But it points me an error near "From Acts". I think # - special symbol in MySQL, anyway, how i can do something like this to avoid enumeration?

Comment: I don't even understand what you are trying to do there.

Comment: i need to create almost copy of record in table, only thre fields will be changed. I dont want to do select with all fields enumerated and try to use temporary table as mediator to avoid enumeration.

Comment: "*avoid field names enumeation inside SELECT clause*" sounds like some really weird thing to do. Why not simply list those columns that you want from the real table?

Comment: @entek, copy acts into temporary table, drop a couple of columns, set the third one to `NOW()`, select and drop the table ;-)

Comment: Actually, specifying the columns you need is a good habit.

Comment: @Michael Krelin - hacker : i know)) but there are so many((, and may be changed.

Comment: Don't use `#` in your table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks much like

```
SELECT
    [list of columns except for id and numOfAct,
     plus 'NOW() as dateOfAct' instead of dateOfAct]
FROM Acts;
```

Comment: is it proper sql query or its explanation of my intention?

Comment: It is explanation of what you should do :)